# How to convert a byteArray to Binary Value in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, binary, type-conversion, byte

I initilaly have a string which is converted to byteArray.
Then I convert this byteArray to HEX as shown below in my code.
Then I further need to convert this to a binary value.

```
        string ID = "A0101185K";
        byte[] ba = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(IC);
        var hexString= BitConverter.ToString(ba).Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: The byte array is a binary value.... I'm not sure I understand what it is you're looking for. Are you asking how to convert the hex string to an array of bool, or how to represent it as a string of 0 and 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert byte to string in that way

```
static string ToBinary(byte b) => Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');
```

and use it in your program like this

```
string MESSAGE = "A0101185K";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(MESSAGE);
var binaries = string.Concat(bytes.Select(ToBinary));
```

I hope that helps you. But of course you didn't tell how you want to store your result, so maybe this is not the right answer.